# PrimeFaces p:textEditor component - readOnly with format

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 6.0.15 and JSF 2.2. I am currently using the component p:textEditor to allow the user to format text (bold, italics, etc.) For example, if I have bolde and underline content, in the DB it would be stored as: `<p><strong><u>TEST</u></strong></p>`.

On the edit mode of my application, I pull the data from the database and because the format is persisted in the DB, it automatically shows the content bolde and underlined. But is there a read only version of the text editor such as  but with the textEditor formatting functionality?

Since what is stored on the DB is pure HTML, I tried doing something like:

```
<h:panelGroup>#{bean.description}</h:panelGroup>
```

But it displayed this: `<p><strong><u>TITLE</u></strong></p>`

How could I display the content so that it shows the formatted content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable HTML insertion without escaping, just set the `escape` attribute of `h:outputText` to `false`:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.description}" escape="false" />
```

> Note: Presenting the HTML input of user A to user B may raise security issues
>    (see: *cross site request forgery*).

Comment: Because of the security reasons, what are my other options?

Comment: I haven't looked into whether PrimeFaces takes any measures to prevent malicious input to this widget. In general you should reject unexpected input rather than trying to fix it. A good read on that quite larger topic: https://martinfowler.com/articles/web-security-basics.html